# Merge [code-folding] and [folding]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

These two tags mean the same thing, at least according to their Wikis.

My preferences:

- master: [code-folding](/questions/tagged/code-folding) (49 Questions)
- synonym:[folding](/questions/tagged/folding) (200+)